# Unable to call Ruby mixin instance method from RSpec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, mixins, rspec3

## Objective:

I want to run a basic RSpec unit test on an instance method of a mixin (module) named Debug. Below are the file contents of the Debug mixin:

#### Mixin File: ./mixins/debug.rb

```
module Debug
  public
    def class_info?
      "#{self.class.name}"
    end
end
```

## Validate Debug mixin instance methods accessible from RSpec:

When I run `irb` and include the Debug mixin with commands `require_relative './mixins/debug.rb'` and `include Debug`, and then call `Debug.class_info?` it successfully returns `"Module"`

Then if I run `rspec` with the following RSpec unit test to confirm that the RSpec context can access the instance methods of the mixin, the test successfully passes:

#### RSpec Unit Test Setup #1: ./spec/mixins/debug_spec.rb

```
require_relative '../../mixins/debug.rb'

RSpec.describe Debug, "#class_info?" do
  include Debug

  before(:each) do
    @class_info_instance_method = Debug.instance_methods[0].to_s
  end

  context "with mixins" do
    it "has class info instance method" do
      expect(@class_info_instance_method).to eq "class_info?"
    end
  end
end
```

## Problem when calling Debug mixin instance method from RSpec:

Lastly, I change the RSpec unit test to be as follows, so instead it actually calls the `class_info?` instance method of the Debug mixin:

#### RSpec Unit Test Setup #2: ./spec/mixins/debug_spec.rb

```
require_relative '../../mixins/debug.rb'

RSpec.describe Debug, "#class_info?" do
  include Debug

  before(:each) do
    @class_info = Debug.class_info?
  end

  context "with mixins" do
    it "shows class info" do
      expect(@class_info).to eq "Module"
    end
  end
end
```

**But now when I run `rspec` from the command line, why does it return the following error?** *(Note: even though in the previous RSpec Unit Test Setup #1 that was entirely similar I checked I could successfully access this Debug mixin instance method)*

```
1) Debug#class_info? with mixins shows class info
   Failure/Error: @class_info = Debug.class_info?

   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `class_info?' for Debug:Module
```

Note: I have shared the above code in my [RubyTest GitHub repo](https://github.com/ltfschoen/RubyTest).

## Setup and References:

#### My System:

- Ruby: ruby 2.3.0p0 (`ruby -v`)
- RSpec: 3.5.4 (`rspec -v`)

#### References:

- Applying example from Mixins chapter of Programming Ruby book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include a module, the methods become instance methods in the included class. `Debug.class_info?` doesn't work because there is no class method `class_info?`. I'm also not sure that the way you've included the module in your test is the best way to do it. Would something like this work?

```
require_relative '../../mixins/debug.rb'

class TestClass
  include Debug
end

RSpec.describe Debug, "#class_info?" do

  let(:test_instance) { TestClass.new }

  context "with mixins" do
    it "shows class info" do
      expect(test_instance.class_info?).to eq "TestClass"
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I solve my original question by changing `class_info?` to `self.class_info?`. But in your example, `test_instance.class_info?` calls the superclass Debug module's instance method `class_info?`. So I updated the Debug module with two methods: `def class_info?; Debug.class_info?; end` and `def self.class_info?; "#{self.class.name}"; end`. To make your test return "TestClass" instead of "Module", I added an override for the `class_info?` instance method in the TestClass (i.e. `def class_info?; "#{self.class.name}" end`) to prevent it calling the instance method of the superclass